# Recursive searching for a continuous path

Tags: java, search, recursion

I am trying to search through a map of sorts. There are Town objects and Path objects. The Towns are connected to the Paths via Town names. So for instance, if you have the name of a town, and you have a name of the second town, you can see if they make a path. Players can control the paths, and if they do, the path turns their color.

I want to recursively search the paths to see if I have a connection from one Town to another via paths. I have included a picture with what I am trying to do. The start is the start parameter, and end is the end. The double lines are the paths that I control, and have my color attached to them.

How the code is written right now, I will get stuck in that second town because it will find that it is a path owned by me and will mark it as visited. I know I have to backtrack in some way but I'm not sure how I would go about it.

```
public boolean continuousPath(Town start, Town end)
{
    //search for towns with the same name
    //as the starting town 
    for(Path p : paths)
    {
        if(p.getStartTown().equals(start))
        {
            matches.add(p); //add it to an arraylist of matches
        }
    }

    //for the matches arrayList
    for(Path pa: matches)
    {
        if(pa.getEndTown().equals(end)){
            matches.clear();
            return true;
        }
        else{
            if(!alreadyVisited(r)){
                if(p.getPlayerColor().equals(colorArray[playerTurn]))
                {
                    visited.add(r);
                    matches.clear();
                    Town tempTown = r.getEndTown();
                    continuousPath(tempTown, end);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public boolean alreadyVisited(Path p)
{
    for(Path pathInstance : visited){
        if(p.getName().equals(pathInstance.getName()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Picture of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is called graph traversal. Check out Dijkstra's Algorithm, it's probably the most straight-forward graph traversal.

http://math.mit.edu/~rothvoss/18.304.3PM/Presentations/1-Melissa.pdf

Comment: Thank you! If instead of starting at the tempTown in my example, I would just start from the beginning, and it would already know I went down those paths. Would upvote if I could

Comment: No problem! And if you want to show appreciation, select my answer as the solution :)